# Why lambda function doesn't work in std::lower_bound while using references in key type?

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, lower-bound

I write this code:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> map_ = {{"b", "1"}, {"a", "2"}};
auto iter = std::lower_bound(map_.begin(), map_.end(), key,
                                     [](auto p1, std::string& rhs) { return p1.first < rhs; });
```

and get such compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at /Users/bestasoff/.../static_map.h:17:38)'
        if (__comp(*__m, __value_))
```

But if I drop `&`, `std::lower_bound` works properly.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the requirements for the predicate in [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) you will see that it should look like

```
bool pred(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

So you can't use reference. Only with `const` qualifier(or pass key by value).

Comment: if I add const qualifier even then it doesn't compile `auto iter = std::lower_bound(map_.begin(), map_.end(), key, [](const auto& p1, const std::string& rhs) { return p1.first < rhs; });`, but if I don't use `auto` it compiles `auto iter = std::lower_bound(map_.begin(), map_.end(), key, [](const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& p1, const std::string& rhs) { return p1.first < rhs; });`

Comment: What compiler and version?

Comment: @KhouriGiordano gcc version 4.8.5 20150623

Comment: Not sure if that version supports auto lambda parameters but I guess it compiled without error. If you wrote the lambda as a stand-alone function it would be a template taking T as it’s first parameter.